# where is the rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check script?

Tags: roslaunch, rostest, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using `rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check()` to check the launch files in a package. It fails with this message on Electric:

```
/bin/sh: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostest/scripts/roslaunch-check.py: not found
```

There is a similar message on Fuerte. There is no test output, but the messages appear to have worked:

```
SUMMARY
 * RESULT: SUCCESS
 * TESTS: 0
 * ERRORS: 0
 * FAILURES: 0
```

I suppose there is some package I should have installed, but can't seem to find it. What do I need to install for this to work correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28227/where-is-the-rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check-script?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the `roslaunch-check.py` script moved from `scripts/` to `bin/`, but the CMake still looks in the wrong place.

I opened a defect ticket: [#3865](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3865).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1